# Read/write files between methods

Tags: python, file

I have two functions, A and B:

```
def A():
    if (exists("temp/my_file.txt"):
        my_file = open("temp/my_file.txt", "r")
        # Do stuff
        my_file.close()
        remove("temp/my_file.txt")

def B():
    my_file = open("temp/my_file.txt", "w")
    # Do other stuff
    my_file.close()
```

These functions are written to separate scripts and run independently. `B()` creates the file which `A()` is supposed to read and then delete. However, I run into various problems with this (Error 2 for instance). I've tried using `posixfile` which doesn't work in Windows, `Lockfile` which gives me import errors, and I've tried writing the file to a temporary directory while I'm using it in `B()` and then moving it back when I want `A()` to read and delete it.

Could I get some insight into what's going on and how I could fix this?

Comment: What's the problem? It's possible to concurrently write to/read from the same file without any issue.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa That's my point; I'm not sure what's going on. But I know that I don't want concurrent read/write either.

Comment: OP, you should be using the `with open("temp/my_file.txt") as f:` syntax for graceful opening and closing of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's quite possible for one to read to a file that's being written to by another thread, it's not possible for either of the threads to delete the file without causing an error.

For example if the read thread deleted the file, the write operations would fail because the file no longer exists. This sounds like a situation where you are better off using a simple message queue, the simplest probably being redis `lpush/rpop` really, it's a lot easier than file io.

If you were to do this with redis,

```
import redis
def A():
    rdb = redis.Redis()
    while True:
        item = rdb.rpop('somekey')
        # do stuff
```

and the writer becomes

```
import redis
def B():
    rdb = redis.Redis()
    while True:
        # do stuff
        rdb.lpush('somekey',item)
```

rpop (and lpop) will wait for data to become available. If you want to stop the loop push in some special value as a signal

Comment: Doesn't that require that both methods be part of the same script?

Comment: So, I looked at the redis documentation but I'm not understanding it. Could you provide some code please?

Comment: you need to use the python redis https://redis-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ the documentation looks scarce because there really isn't anything to it.

Comment: How is this answer related to the original question? Why add an unnecessary dependency on redis to just handle files?